# Inaccessible Facebook application created under a Business account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, user-accounts

When I try to access https://developers.facebook.com/apps when logged in as a business account it redirects me back to my homepage and won't let me access an app that we had created under our account earlier.

We validated that the app exists for the business account by going to the Graph API Explorer and selecting our application from the dropdown.

After checking on stackoverflow for similar issues we found this: [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account).

We have this "bug or loophole" in our case.  We have a business account that has apps that were created under it at some point that we can no longer access. We would like help migrating the app to a verified personal account. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It really doesn't look like there is any reference to an issue like this on any of the support/help centers. The only thing I could suggest to you would be to fill out this [disabled account appeal form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/260749603972907)... It's slightly unrelated to your issue but it still allows you to enter an email for identification and some free text to explain the issue..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the disabled account appeal form if your account has not been disabled. This issue is happening to me. Since we are a visitor's bureau for a city, we can only access our Page (visit cheyenne), not our business account (cheyenne wyoming). So, we can't access https://developers.facebook.com/apps